# Kryo: IdentityObjectIntMap.clear() produces enormous CPU load

Tags: java, performance, serialization, concurrency, kryo

I need to serialize a lot of objects in my application with Kryo. A few of them are really large object graphs, others are just small containers with a few primitives (but there are a *lot* of these containers). These serialization processes can happen in several threads concurrently (on different data elements).

According to the documentation:

1. A `Kryo` instance is not thread safe.
2. Creating a new `Kryo` instance is expensive.

The logical conclusion for me was to have a `ThreadLocal<WeakReference<Kryo>>` that acts as a cache for initialized `Kryo` instances.

However, JVisualVM now shows me that the method `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.IdentityObjectIntMap.clear()` is consuming 90% of the CPU time (self time) of my application. To me, this looks as if Kryo needs to somehow "reset" itself in between serialization processes, and apparently this operation is rather expensive.

Does anybody have a clue what might be going on here and why this operation brings my application performance down so much, or how I can do better than with a thread-local weak reference cache for `Kryo` instances?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Kryo#setReference(false)`.

With:

```
Kryo#setReference(true)
```

Kryo tracks read/write objects.
And Internally, Kryo uses `IdentityObjectIntMap` to manage read/write object.

```
Kryo#setReference(false)
```

will stop tracking read/write objects, so `IdentityObjectIntMap#clear` will not be called anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a pool of Kryo instances, and reset the instance every time you release an instance to the pool.

There is now an official pool implementation in Kryo, see [KryoPool](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/pool/KryoPool.java) (since v3 afaik), or others projects which implement this strategy.